# Cumulative sales based on ID and order of date

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field, cumulative-sum, accumulate

I am trying to create a calculated field that sums up the cumulative sales (the sales column is not shown in the picture below) per month per ID value based on the months that the ID contains a sale. Basically what I want is to be able to see that for ID 44, month 4/30/2018 has 4 sales, then on 6/30/2018 has 10 sales and so on, all the way up to 8/31/2018 with 39 sales. Then it calculates the sales for ID 49 and ID 91 based on the months present. I've been trying out different formulas on how to do this, but nothing have work yet. I am currently using Tableau 2019.4.

[Here is a sample of the data I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knMhJ.png)

I've also asked this question on Tableau Community Forums, if you'd like to answer it over on Tableau, here is the link: https://community.tableau.com/message/1029895#1029895

Answer (score 0):

If you want this as a calculated field, then you would have to use the `FIXED` function:

```
{ FIXED [Column1],[Columns2]: SUM([Sales]) }
```

The following link can explain the basics of the function and how it can be useful:

https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_fixed.htm

If you want a simple calculation grouped up then, all you have to do is put the Column1 and Column2 in Columns and the sum(sales) in the rows of a table visualization.